# Symlinked folder cannot be opened

Tags: arch-linux, symlink

Can someone explain this?

ls displays the symlink
`$ ls -l .config/blender 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rain rain 29 Aug  7 13:48 .config/blender -> SpiderOakHive/config/blender/`

but this fails
`$ ls -l .config/blender/
ls: cannot access .config/blender/: No such file or directory`

Yet, the symlinked folder definitely exists according to this (empty newlines removed):

`$ ls -lR SpiderOakHive/
SpiderOakHive/:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 rain rain 4096 Aug  7 04:13 config
SpiderOakHive/config:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 rain rain 4096 Aug  7 03:32 blender
SpiderOakHive/config/blender:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 rain rain 4096 Aug  7 03:32 2.75
SpiderOakHive/config/blender/2.75:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 rain rain 4096 Aug  7 03:32 config
SpiderOakHive/config/blender/2.75/config:
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 rain rain 115248 Aug  7 03:32 userpref.blend`

I don't see anything off with the permissions and other symlinks seem to be working.

System:

`$ uname -a
Linux acidcloud 4.1.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 3 21:30:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should point to  `../SpiderOakHive/config/blender/` instead of `SpiderOakHive/config/blender/`

Comment: Or maybe even more `../`s, I'm a little bit confused with your directory structure.

Comment: oh, thanks it works, I suspected it was something obvious.
...and it's even in the manpage, I feel so stupid now.